# ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'en-core-web-sm'

Tags: python, module, package, spacy, pipenv

I'm trying to deploy an app that uses en_core_web_sm which is a sub-module of spacy. In my code I had `import en_core_web_sm` and it worked fine when locally testing. In my venv I ran pipenv install `spacy[en-core-web-sm]` which produced this in the Pipfile: `spacy = {extras = ["en-core-web-sm"], version = "*"}.` I've tried multiple ways of importing this into my .py file but keep getting the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I've tried importing from `en-core-web-sm`, `en_core_web_sm`, `spacy['en_core_web_sm]`, `spacy.lang.en-core-web-sm`, among many other variations.

I've also tried `en_core_web_sm = __import__('en-core-web-sm')` and `en_core_web_sm = __import__('spacy["en-core-web-sm"]')` as I understand modules with dashes can be problematic when importing.

What's the right way to import this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Now, if you run for example:

```
string = "going went gone"
[token.lemma_ for token in nlp(string)] #lemmatization
```

you will get:

```
['go', 'go', 'go']
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Was trying to avoid importing the full spacy package but oh well